# How to resolve the dependency issue in Ubuntu 16.04 while installing VLC?

Tags: 16.04, apt, dependencies, vlc

[image: dependency Error.png]

I am trying to install VLC player form this link: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/06/install-vlc-3-0-ubuntu. I am gettting the errors which are shown in the image. Could any one please help me with this.

Errors:

```
praveen@IOT-1124:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwx-perl:i386 : Depends: perl:i386 (>= 5.22.1-2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: perlapi-5.22.1:i386
                   Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:3.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libwxbase3.0-0v5:i386 (>= 3.0.2+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libwxgtk-media3.0-0v5:i386 (>= 3.0.2+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5:i386 (>= 3.0.2+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: wxperl-gtk2-3-0-2-uni-gcc-3-4:i386
                   Depends: libalien-wxwidgets-perl:i386 (>= 0.65+dfsg~) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libgles2-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles2
       Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libva-drm1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 0):

Open up a new terminal session and try updating your system first:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

Then install VLC from the Ubuntu Repository:

`sudo apt-get install vlc`

Comment: I have tried the same, it is not working. How to resolve that dependencies issue. it is coming for every installation.

Comment: Try and run `sudo apt-get -f install` This will install any dependencies that might have been missed during installation.

Answer (score 0):

first of all download Debian package for Ubuntu of VLC media player from https://www.videolan.org/vlc/#download

Now you can proceed in either way:

1. - use command line `$ sudo dpkg -i <path/to/package.deb>`

or

2. - Install GDebi package Installer from Ubuntu software center or from command line.
   - Now install the downloaded Debian package with GDebi package Installer